# Is it neccessary to add migration if new table is added in Room database?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

***I have two tables,person is already existing(added column userid as 
    foreign key)***

```
    @Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
    data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = CLIENT_ID) var id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = USER_ID)var userId : Int = 1) : Parcelable {}
```

***this is the newly added class,which has foreign key of person 
    class(userid)***

```
    @Entity(tableName = Profile.TABLE_NAME,
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity= Person::class,
    parentColumns = [(Person.USER_ID)],
    childColumns = [(Profile.USER_ID)],
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)])
    @Parcelize
    data class Profile(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var userId: Int,
    var name: String? = null):Parcelable{}
```

***Here i have two tables in the DB.
    Now,do i need to write migration code for creation of new table?***

Comment: refer [this](https://medium.com/@magdamiu/android-room-persistence-library-queries-and-migration-support-a9f21d2dc9d8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to migrate your data from the previous version to the new version
then

> **Yes. You have to write the migration code.**

If you only want to migrate schema and not data.
then no need to write migration logic. Just add `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` in Room builder.

**Example:**

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build();
```